# Don't know which type of array to use C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to create a mini quiz with 10 questions and 3 answers to each of them. So I have an array with questions and an array with correct answers to them. But I don't know which array to use for all answers ( correct ones and incorrect ones). Note: I will shuffle every array to randomize everything.

Comment: C# is an object oriented language. Create an object that represents a question, with properties that contain the question text, the correct answer, and the incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box array type that will fit your requirements. You could create some types that store and process the quiz data. Example:

```
public class Answer
{
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; } = false;
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
}

public class Quiz
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>();
}

var question1 = new Question()
{
    Text = "When should I use an array instead of List<T>?",
    Answers = new List<Answer>
    {
        new Answer() {IsTrue = true, Text = "If you don't know what a generic is."},
        new Answer() {IsTrue = false, Text = "If you want to save tons of memory."},
        new Answer() {IsTrue = false, Text = "If you want faster code."},
    }
};

var quiz = new Quiz();
quiz.Questions.Add(question1);
```